# Add the values of product meta as fee in WooCommerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart, fee

In Italy there is a specific fee for the disposal of electronic products that must be paid during the purchase.

This "ecofee" is specific for each product.

I have set up a specific meta for each product called `meta_product_grossecofee`

I'd like to convert the value of this meta field in a fee on the cart.

This is the code I've tried, however without the desired result. Any advice?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'ecofee_display' );
function ecofee_display(){
    global $product;
    $ecofee = $product->get_meta('meta_product_grossecofee');
    if ($ecofee) {

        WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Ecofee: ', 'txtdomain'), $ecofee);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cart can contain multiple products, so `global $product` is not applicable here.

Instead, you can go through the cart and for each product for which the meta exists, add the value for this to the fee.

If the $fee is greater than 0, you can then apply it.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    
    // Initialize
    $fee = 0;
    
    // Loop through cart contents
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart_contents() as $cart_item ) {
        // Get meta
        $ecofee = $cart_item['data']->get_meta( 'meta_product_grossecofee', true );

        // NOT empty & variable is a number
        if ( ! empty ( $ecofee ) && is_numeric( $ecofee ) ) {               
            // Addition
            $fee += $ecofee;
        }
    }

    // If greater than 0
    if ( $fee > 0 ) {
        // Add additional fee (total)
        $cart->add_fee( __( 'Ecofee', 'woocommerce' ), $fee, false );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'action_woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 10, 1 );
```

---

**Note:** if you want to take into account the quantity per product:

Replace

```php
// NOT empty & variable is a number
if ( ! empty ( $ecofee ) && is_numeric( $ecofee ) ) {               
    // Addition
    $fee += $ecofee;
}
```

With

```php
// NOT empty & variable is a number
if ( ! empty ( $ecofee ) && is_numeric( $ecofee ) ) {
    // Get product quantity in cart  
    $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
    
    // Addition
    $fee += $ecofee * $quantity;
}
```

Comment: I feel very stupid for not thinking that global $product cannot be used in this case. :-) The code you wrote is perfect and not easy. Thank you very much for your invaluable help